# Which Pattern Matching Algorithm fits for my case?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, arraylist

I have a project which it needs to compare to text documents and find the similarity rate between every single sentence and the general similarities of the texts.
I did some transforming on texts like lowering all words,deleting duplicate words,deleting punctuations except fullstops. After doing some operations, i had 2 arraylists which include sentences and the words all seperated. It looks like

> [["hello","world"],["welcome","here"]]

Then i sorted every sentence alphabetically.After all these, i'm comparing all the words one by one,doing linear search but if the word which i'm searching is bigger than i'm looking (ASCII of first character like world > burger) ,i'm not looking remaining part,jumping other word. It seems like complicated but i need an answer of " Is there any faster,efficient common algorithms like Boyer Moore,Hashing or other?" . I'm not asking any code peace but i need some theoretical advices.Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I should've tell the main purpose of the project. Actually it is kinda plagiarism detector.There are two txt files which are main.txt and sub.txt.The program will compare them and it gives an output something like that:

```
Output:
Similarity rate of two texts is: %X
{The most similar sentence}
{The most similar 2nd sentence}
{The most similar 3d sentence}
{The most similar 4th sentence}
{The most similar 5th sentence}
```

So i need to find out sub.txt similarity rate to main.txt file.I thought that i need to compare all the sentences in two files with each other.

> For instance, main.txt has 10 sentences and sub.txt has 5 sentences,
> there will be 50 comparison and 50 similarity rate will be calculated
> and stored.

Finally i sort the similarty rates and print the most 5 sentences.Actually i've done the project,but it's not efficient. It has 4 nested for loops and compares all words uncountable times and complexity becomes like O(n^4) ( maybe not that much) but it's really huge even in the worst case. I found Levenshtein distance algorithm and Cosine similarity algorithms but i'm not sure about them. Thanks for any suggestion!

**EDIT2:**
For my case similarity between 2 sentence is like:

```
main_sentence:"Hello dude how are you doing?"
sub_sentence:"Hello i'm fine dude."
Since intersection is 2 words ["hello","dude"]
The similarity is : (length of intersected words)*100/(length of main text)
For this case it's: 2*100/6 = %33,3
```

Comment: Please provide some details on what you are expecting the results of the comparison to be. Are you looking for the number of words that are the same in each list? Or just checking if they contain exactly the same words? It's not clear in your question.

Comment: @sprinter You are right. I added EDIT part to my question. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I think we need a more strict definition of similar to solve this.

Comment: @Surt I added a strict definition in EDIT2. Thank you.

Comment: I believe there's enough info in order to, at least, start resolving the issue. Do not close this, as could be a interesting thread. Please.

Comment: Hello @aran. If your last comment was for me, i'm working on this project thanks for your really helpful suggestions. Also i have another projects currently and i'm working on them :)

Comment: @NaregBoynukalın it was directed to users with close privileges. This question had a vote for closing, that's why I made the comment. May you have luck my friend! As a suggestion....image recognition would work here ; )

Comment: @aran Thank you very much! I think this thread will help people in the future by your and other ones help, it wouldn't be nice to close. You know what, i'm kinda working on machine learning and i really tought about image recognition :) But this is not our case at least now :)

Comment: @NaregBoynukalın I used to work with machine learning, as my Master's degree's final project was focused on recognition of fatigue based on car driver's hearth rate variability. I love d that world, but know I work as data architect (money rules). Have fun and good luck my friend : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, and even if this is not a "complete answer" to your issue, comparing Strings is usually a "heavy" operation (even if you first check their length, which, in fact, is one of the first things the `equals()` method already performs when comparing Strings)

What I suggest is doing next: create a `dummy hashcode()-like` method. It won't be a real `hashcode()`, but the number associated to the order in which that word was read by your code. Something like a cryptographic method, but much simpler.

Note that `string.hashCode()` won't work, as the word "Hello" from the first document wouldn't return the same hashcode than the word "Hello" from the second document.

---

### Data "Warming" - PreConversion

Imagine you have a shared `HashMap<String,Integer>` (`myMap`), which key is an String and the value an Integer. *Note that HashMap's hashing in java with String keys lower than 10 characters (which usually are, in english language) is incredibly fast*. Without any check, just put each word with its counter value:

```
  myMap.put(yourString, ++counter);
```

Let's say you have 2 documents:

```
 1.txt-   Welcome mate what are you doing here 
     
 2.txt-   Mate I was here before are you dumb
```

I assume you already lowercased all words, and removed duplicates.
You start reading the first document and assigning each word to a number. The map would look like:

```
        KEY                     VALUE
       welcome                    1
       mate                       2
       what                       3
       are                        4
       you                        5
       doing                      6
       here                       7
```

Now with the second document. If a key is repeated, the put() method will update its value. So:

```
        KEY                     VALUE
       welcome                    1
       mate                       8
       what                       3
       are                        13
       you                        14
       doing                      6
       here                       11
         I                        9
       was                        10
       before                     12
       dumb                       15
```

Once complete, you create another HashMap<Integer,String> (`reverseMap`), this way in reverse:

```
       KEY                    VALUE
       1                       welcome
       8                       mate
       3                       what
       13                       are
       14                       you
       6                       doing
       11                       here
        9                        I
       10                        was
       12                     before
       15                       dumb
```

You convert both documents into a List of Integers, so they look like:

```
 1.txt-   Welcome mate what are you doing here
 2.txt-   Mate I was here before are you dumb
```

to:

```
 listOne - [1, 8, 3, 13, 14, 6, 11]
 listTwo - [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

---

### Duplicate words, positions and sequences

To find the duplicated within both documents:

- First, create a deep clone of one of the lists, for example, listTwo. A deep clone of a `List` of `Integers` is relatively easy to perform. Calling it `listDuplicates` as that will be its objective.

  ```
     List<Integer> listDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Integer i:listTwo)
            listDuplicates.add(new Integer(i));
  ```
- Call `retainAll`:

`listDuplicates.retainAll(listOne);`

The result would be:

```
listDuplicates- [8,11,13,14]
```

So, from a total of `listOne.size()+listTwo.size() = 15` words found on 2 documents, 4 are duplicates are 11 are unique.

In order to get the converted values, just call:

```
for (Integer i : listDuplicates)
 System.out.println(reverseMap.get(i)); // mate , here, are, you
```

Now that duplicates are identified, `listOne` and `listTwo` can also be used now in order to:

- Identify the position on each list (so we can get the difference in the positions of this words).  The first word would have -1 value, as its the first one and doesn't have a diff with the previous one, but won't necessarily mean they are consequent with any other (they are just the first duplicates).

If the next element has -1 value, that means the [8] and [11] would aslo be consecutive:

```
          doc1   doc2   difDoc1     difDoc2
    [8]     2      1     -1  (0-1)   -1  (0-1)
    [11]    7      4     -5  (2-7)   -3  (1-4)
    [13]    4      6      3  (7-4)   -2  (4-6)
    [14]    5      7     -1  (4-5)   -1  (6-7)
```

In this case, the distance shown in `[14]` with its previous duplicate *(the diff between `[13]` and `[14]`)* is the same in both documents: **-1**: that means that not only are duplicates, but both are consequently placed in both documents.

Hence, we've found not only duplicate words, but also a **duplicate sequence** of two words between those lines:

`[13][14]`--**`are you`**

The same mechanism (identifying a **diff of -1** for the same variable in both documents) would also help to find a complete duplicate sequence of 2 or more words. If all the duplicates show a diff of -1 in both documents, that means we've found a **complete duplicate line**:

In this example this is shown clearer:

```
   doc1- "here i am" [4,5,6]
   doc2- "here i am" [4,5,6]
```

`listDuplicates - [4,5,6]`

```
              doc1   doc2   difDoc1     difDoc2
        [4]    1      1      -1  (0-1)   -1  (0-1)
        [5]    2      2      -1  (1-2)   -1  (1-2)
        [6]    3      3      -1  (2-3)   -1  (2-3)
```

All the diffs are **-1** for the same variable  in both documents -> all duplicates are next to each other in both documents --> **The sentence is exactly the same in both documents**. So, this time, **we've found a complete duplicate line of 3 words**.

`[4][5][6]` -- **`here i am`**

Apart of this duplicate sequence search, this difference table would also be helpful when calculating the variance, median,... from the duplicate words, in order to get some kind of "similarity" factor *(something like a basic indicative value of equity between documents. By no mean definitive, but somehow helpful)*

---

### Unique values - helpful in order to get a non-equity indicative ?

Similar mechanisms would be used to get those unique values. For example, by removing the duplicates from the `reverseMap`:

```
for (Integer i: listDuplicates)
    reverseMap.remove(i);
```

Now the reverseMap only contains unique values. `reverseMap.size() = 11`

```
   KEY                     VALUE
   1                       welcome
   3                       what
   6                       doing
   9                       I
   10                      was
   12                      before
   15                      dumb
```

In order to get the unique words:

`reverseMap.values() = {welcome,what,doing,I,was,before,dumb}`

If you need to know which unique words are from which document, you could use the `reverseMap` (as the Lists may be altered after you execute methods such as retainAll on them):

- Count the number of words from the 1st document. This time, 7.
- If the key of the reverseMap is <=7, that unique word comes from the 1st document. `{welcome,what,doing}`
- If the key is >7, that unique word comes from the 2nd document. `{I,was,before,dumb}`

The uniqueness factor could also be another indicative, this way, a negative one (as we are searching for similarities here). Still could be really helpful.

---

### equals and hashCode - avoid

As the `hashcode()` method for Strings won't return the same value for two same words (only for two same String Object references), wouldn't work here. `String.equals()` method works by comparing the chars (also checks for the length, as you do manually) which would be total overkill if used for big documents:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {  
      if (this == anObject) {  
          return true;  
      }  
      if (anObject instanceof String) {  
          String anotherString = (String) anObject;  
          int n = value.length;  
          if (n == anotherString.value.length) {  
              char v1[] = value;  
              char v2[] = anotherString.value;  
              int i = 0;  
              while (n-- != 0) {  
                  if (v1[i] != v2[i])  
                          return false;  
                  i++;  
              }  
              return true;  
          }  
      }  
      return false;  
  }
```

My oppinion is to avoid this as much as possible, specially hashCode() should never be used, as:

```
String one = "hello";
String two = "hello"; 

one.hashCode() != two.hashCode()
```

There's an exception to this, but only when the compiler interns strings; Once you load thousands of them, that won't ever again be used by the compiler. In those rare cases where both String Objects reference the same cached memory address, this will also be true:

```
one.hashCode() == two.hashCode() --> true
one == two --> true
```

But those are really unusual exceptions, and once string internship doesn't kick, those `hashCodes` won't be equal and the operator `==` to compare Strings will return `false` even if the Strings hold the same value (as usual, because it works comparing their memory addresses).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sure coverting the each unique word into integers like giving them IDs , will decrease running time a lot or i hope so :) Also i added EDIT part to my question. You can check it :)

Comment: HI @NaregBoynukalın, just a question... Is it relevant the position of each text? I mean, if you have two pages from two documents... Do you take into account if "Hello there" is repeated in the first lines of both documents....

Comment: or is it relevant if one of "hello there" is at the start of the page in the first document, and another "hello there" is at the end of the 2nd document? Hope I'm explaining here

Comment: Hi @aran.Actually no it's not. "Hello there" statement can be in the first line of first document and also can be 5th line of 2nd document. Then i say, the common statement between first line of first doc. and 5th line of 2nd document is "Hello there" . Then i calculate similarity rate between these sentences.

Comment: Would you consider a line of text to be the "element" to compare? Like, splitting complete lines and comparing them?

Comment: Like a first filter at least, without seeking for word similarities yet

Comment: @NaregBoynukalın updated with some extra info regarding identifying duplicate sequences with the help of the identified duplicate words. Anyway, I wanted to suggest something....much different. If you could consider an entire line as a "node", I have a suggestion to make

Comment: Hello @aran , i checked your common sequence detection and i mostly could implement it in Java. It works like charm when each sentence has all unique values same as you gave listOne - [1, 8, 3, 13, 14, 6, 11] and listTwo - [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]. But i need some genious ideas about what if there is duplicate value in lists. For example i'm adding [8,10] sequence to both lists and they become   listOne - [1, 8, 3, 13, 14,8,10 6, 11] and listTwo - [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,8,10 15]. Since the 8 and 10 values are duplicate it causes a problem. Next Comment ->>

Comment: When i want to find the index of second 8 and 10 , it finds the indexes of first 8 and 10. So the diff doesnt became "-1" for [8,10] sequence. I need your help again :)

Comment: Seriously,i'm stuck . I've tried seperating all meaningless subsequences and then comparing them each other. I did it, but complexity became O(n^4). I need more efficient something. Please help :)

Comment: @NaregBoynukalın sorry for this late response. I promise coming again with something (but I must think know...). Bookmarked this, so I won't lose the path of the question

Answer (score 1):

The essential technique is to see this is as a multi-stage process. The key is that you're not trying to compare every document with every other document, but rather, you have a first pass that identifies small clusters of likely matches in essentially a one-pass process:

(1) Index or cluster the documents in a way that will allow *candidate* matches to be identified;

(2) Identify candidate documents that may be a match based on those indexes/clusters;

(3) For each cluster or index match, have a scoring algorithm that scores the similarity of a given pair of documents.

There are a number of ways to solve (1) and (3), depending on the nature and number of the documents. Options to consider:

- For certain datasets, (1) could be as simple as indexing on unusual words/clombinations of words
- For more complex documents and/or larger datasets, you will need to do something sometimes called 'dimension reduction': rather than clustering on shared combinations of words, you'll need to cluster on combinations of shared features, where each feature is identified by a set of words. Look at a feature extraction technique sometimes referred to as "latent semantic indexing" -- essentially, you model the documents mathematically as a matrix of "words per feature" multiplied by "feature per document", and then by factorising the matrix you arrive at an approximation of a set of features, along with a weighted list of which words make up each feature
- Then, once you have a means of identifying a set of words/features to index on, you need some kind of indexing function that will mean that candidate document matches have identical/similar index keys. Look at cosine similarity and "locality-sensitive hashing" such as SimHash.
- Then for (3), given a small set of candidate documents (or documents that cluster together in your hashing system), you need a similarity metric. Again, what method is appropriate depends on your data, but conceptually, one way you could see this as "for each sentence in document X, find the most similar document in document Y and score its similarity; obtain a 'plagiarism score' that his the sum of these values". There are various ways to define 'similarity score' between two strings: e.g. longest common subsequence, edit distance, number of common word pairs/sequences...

As you can probably imagine from all of this, there's no single algorithm that will hand you exactly what you need on a plate. (That's why entire companies and research departments are dedicated to this problem...) But hopefully the above will give you some pointers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think cases like "plagiarism" needs to implement longest common sequence. If i understood well, that means find the longest common sequences between two sentences. It can be 2 or 3 common words sequence like between "Today is a good day " and " Today is a bad day" has 3 words common sequence "Today is a" .Then we calculate a score depends on the length of sequence. Am i right till now ?

Comment: Usually the way LCS is defined is that it can "skip" non-matches, so "I am a good day" and "I am a bad day" would match on the subsequence "I am a (...) day" (i.e. measuring the number of characters that occur in the same order in the two strings, skipping intervening characters.) But you could also define it the way you suggest (sometimes a difference is made between "subsequence" and "substring" to denote this difference). More sophisticated algorithms would also try and build in some error tolerance (which might be referred to as 'longest common subsequence with k mismatches', for example).